# Server side: php hack $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']

Tags: php, wordpress, ip

On dedicated boxes we host a few sites with sensible content, mainly using wordpress. To enforce the privacy and confidentiality of our visitors we want to remove completely their IP address.

Wordpress gets the IP address for a few things: members login, comments, "like", stats, etc etc. 
We admins do not need the IP addresses and want to remove (or forge) them everywhere the can be read by wordpress and its modules.

One way would be to run some cron tasks to alter them into the databases. But as we have a lot of visitors, that does not look very convenient.

That is why we are considering hacking the $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] value, either by writing for example 127.0.0.1, or a fully random address. That should be done in the php "kernel" itself,

how can we do this?

Thank you.

Comment: Run an nginx reverse proxy in front of the website and don't pass the source IP through.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Unfortunately, it is not a code writing service, it is a website for solving code problems. Please come back when you have some.

Comment: Thank *you* for being so considerate. As Alex said, put any kind of reverse proxy before your PHP app and disable its access log (or configure a log format that doesn't contain IP addresses). A cache like Varnish may give you double benefits.